# LinearLayout addView with index error

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In ScrollView I have a LinearLayout. Inside this LinearLayout I can't add view with index.

Why?

example:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.android_messenger_sent_message, null);
TextView inbox_message = (TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.sentMessage);
inbox_message.setText(conversationInfo.getBody()+" "+conversationInfo.getId());
linearLayoutGlobal.addView(relativeLayout,i);
```

where `i` is an integer from 1 000 000 and it is getting smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add to position 1 000 000 if there are no views. :) Try to use `addView(relativeLayout)` instead of the indexed version.

If you need to add in reverse order, then use `addView(relativeLayout, 0)`. This will keep on inserting on the head of the list, thus, tossing the aready added views behind.

Note: adding 1M views to a single scroll view will surely fail because you run out of resources. Try with a lower number or change to `ListView`.

Comment: That was not exactly solution to my problem but I used it and changed some of my code here and there. Thanks!